# Add extra condition on laravel eloquent select

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Almost every table on my system has a field `id_unity`, which is used to control which unity the registry are from.

I wanna know if is possible to changed `->get()` and `->lists()` methods from eloquent to add

```
->where('id_unity',Session::get('unity');
```

before every select, so I'll just do:

```
Products::all(); //and that actually will be 
Products::where('id_unity',Session::get('unity'));
```

Anyone? ;)

Comment: Check out global scopes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use query scopes:

```
public function scopeGetAll($query)
{
   return $query->where('id_unity', Session::get('unity'))->get();
}
```

You then call it statically without the "scope" prefix:

```
Products::getAll();
```

If you want to make it available to all models, just create a Base model class which your models extend, in which you define that function.

Base.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Session;

class Base extends Model {

    public function scopeGetAll($query)
    {
       return $query->where('id_unity', Session::get('unity'))->get();
    }    
}
```

Products.php

```
use Base;
class Products extends Base {

}
```

Comment: Perfect!!!! Worked exactly how I needed! Just waiting 4 minutes to choose your answer! Thanks a lot ;)